# Remove or Rename "Site" Tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I posted a question about Active Directory Sites, so I looked for a tag specific to it. The [sites tag](https://serverfault.com/tags/site/info) appears to have questions relating to websites, Active Directory Sites, SharePoint Sites, DNS, etc. This tag is not good for organizing questions because it is too generic.

Comment: Yes, this is a bad tag.  I'm thinking removal is the preferable course of action.

Comment: Seeing as how most questions on it seem to relate to websites, perhaps synonym it to website? Then again it has a very limited amount of questions as is, so removal wouldn't impact much.

Comment: Down with the `site`!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the [site](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/site) tag is no more so this is completed.

<sup>Just providing an answer so that this can be considered answered.</sup>